# How to save echo on bash as variable?

Tags: bash

how can I get to echo and save as variable?

```
sm@tp1:~/pc$ php get.php | grep "PhP" | cut -c24-33 | sed -n 1p
PhP 47.813
```

this is the output

```
sm@tp1:~/pc$ out=$(php get.php | grep "PhP" | cut -c24-33 | sed -n 1p) | echo $out
sm@tp1:~/pc$
```

but in here there is no output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second line you are assigning the output to the variable `out`.  If you later want to see what the variable `out` is, just type `echo $out` afterwards:

```
sm@tp1:~/pc$ out=$(php get.php | grep "PhP" | cut -c24-33 | sed -n 1p)
sm@tp1:~/pc$ echo $out
```

In other words, don't use the pipe `|` and just echo on another line, or you can just replace that pipe with a semicolon `;`.

```
sm@tp1:~/pc$ out=$(php get.php | grep "PhP" | cut -c24-33 | sed -n 1p); echo $out
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add , In this case

```
    out=$(php get.php | grep "PhP" | cut -c24-33 | sed -n 1p)|echo $out
```

Each of the command shall run in separate subshell where you can pipe stdout as stdin but passing variable is not possible.
In your case variable is out